# Multiple unknown node versions from brew

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to run `yarn add` command and I get the error:

`Node version 0.12.4 is not supported, please use Node.js 4.0 or higher.`

When I run `node -v` I get:

`v0.12.4`

But when I run `brew upgrade node` I get the error:

`Error: node 12.6.0 already installed`

Any ideas on how to deal with this? Have I installed different node versions twice by mistake from somewhere?

I have tried running `brew uninstall node` followed by `brew install node`, after which `node -v` still gives me: `v0.12.4`

Comment: Looks like I had installed node back in 2012 via the official DMG installer. I uninstalled that, and `node -v` is now using the brew version as default..